# How to make a crossplatform mobile application?

Tags: android, ios7

How to prepare a cross platform mobile application? Please guide.
Any alternative to phone gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions available worldwide.
You can use XMLVM,Mono Touch, rhomobile, Sencha Touch, Corona, Codename One and last but not the least PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is the next one, and I think it is quite complete. But I think there are a lot out there. In Google can search: "hybrid applications in html5" and it may say something.